# MS Project Read Project Custom Fields

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I need to retrieve values of custom fields assigned to Project. These custom fields are Enterprise fields create in PWA. In the [Interop.MSProject.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject._iprojectdoc.text1?view=office-project-server#microsoft-office-interop-msproject-iprojectdoc-text1) there are similar in name properties "Text1 - 10". But when I read any of 10 fields all of these are empty.
Also, object of Project does not have [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.getfield) method like on Resource to get value via GetField method with using [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant).

The assigned value in the mpp file to the Project looks like this
[image]

Could anybody advice how this enterprise custom field value "CF1 Value Server" can be retrieved from MPP file with using Interop.MSProject.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the values in the project-level enterprise custom fields, use the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) method to get the Field ID. Then use the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.getfield) method of the [Project summary task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.projectsummarytask).

```
Dim fldCF1 As Long
fldCF1 = Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Text CF 1")

Dim CF1 As String
CF1 = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.GetField(fldCF1)
```